# Unable to install @angular/common/http using npm

Tags: angular, npm

Until yesterday, I was able to download @angular/common/http package. However starting from today, every time I issue

```
npm i
```

command, I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME npm ERR! Invalid package name
>   "@angular/common/http": name can only contain URL- friendly characters

People have suggested to upgrade/downgrade npm which I have tried but no luck so far.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common/http": "^5.0.0",
```

Any ideas guys? let me know if you need more info.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `@angular/common/http` module is part of the `@angular/common` module. You only need to include `@angular/common` within your dependencies, not the http module as well.

Adding `@angular/common/http` to your package json will try to include it a second time when you already have it. Remove it, delete your node_modules folder and rerun `npm install`

Comment: sweet - you have saved me from hours of misery. Already invested couple of hours pulling my hair. And what you said makes sense. I just tried and it did work. Thanks a million.

Comment: this saved me, I was updating an older app with angular 2 and @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/animations was causing the same issues, removing it fixed the install

Comment: @JKing glad this answer could help you